# Deserialize XML string to Object VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I've seen plenty of examples online but either I cannot make sense of the application or the example is too different from mine for me to transpose. I have a XML

```
<Interfaces>
    <Interface>
        <InterfaceCode>987</InterfaceCode>
        <AccessID>asdf</AccessID>
        <Password>654321</Password>
    </Interface>
    <Interface>
        <InterfaceCode>789</InterfaceCode>
        <AccessID>      </AccessID>
        <Password>      </Password>
    </Interface>
</Interfaces>
```

And the following classes

```
<Serializable(), XmlRoot("Interfaces"), XmlType("Interfaces")>
Public Class InterfacesModel
    Property Interfaces As New List(Of InterfaceModel)
End Class

<Serializable(), XmlType("Interface")>
Public Class InterfaceModel
    Property InterfaceCode As String
    Property AccessID As String
    Property Password As String
End Class
```

The following code produces a `InterfacesModel` with an empty `Interfaces` list:

```
Dim str As String = xmlString
Dim interfaces As InterfacesModel

Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(InterfacesModel))
Using reader As TextReader = New StringReader(str)
     interfaces = serializer.Deserialize(reader)
End Using
```

I would expect it to populate Interfaces as a List(of InterfaceModel) so that I can perform a for each on Interfaces and do something to each Interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `XmlElement("Interface")` on your property. Also, you can get rid of the XmlType attributes. I don't think those are doing anything for you.

```
<Serializable(), XmlRoot("Interfaces")>
Public Class InterfacesModel
    <XmlElement("Interface")> Property Interfaces As New List(Of InterfaceModel)
End Class

<Serializable()>
Public Class InterfaceModel
    Property InterfaceCode As String
    Property AccessID As String
    Property Password As String
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

When im writing serializable classes i dont use  tags i just use something like this and it works the same

```
<Serializable>
Public Class Interfaces
    Public interface as InterfaceModel() 'The () Defines an array of InterFaceModels
End Class

<SerialzableAttribute>
Public Class InterfaceModel
    Public InterFaceCode As String
    Public AccessID As String
    Public Password As String
End Class
```