# Having an issue with XML containing nested objects to POCO (de)serialisation (VB.Net)

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net, serialization

I've created an SP in SQL Server that returns as XML. I decided to do this as the information has contacts and addresses in it and I wanted to reduce the amount of data I get.

```
<Accounts>
  <Account>
    <Company />
    <ContactNumber />
    <Addresses>
      <Address>
        <Line1 />
        ....
      </Address>
    <Addresses>
    <Contacts>
       <Contact>
         <Name />
          ....
       </Contact>
   <Account>
</Accounts>
```

I have found SqlCommand.ExecuteXmlReader but I'm confused as to how to serialise this into my POCO. Can someone point me at what my next step is. (The POCO was created by the Insert XML as a class menu item in VS2019).

My Google fu is letting me down as I'm not sure what I should be looking for to help understand how to serialize the XML into something that will allow me to go with Foreach Account in AccountsClass type logic.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS The XML above is just a sample to show what I'm doing. The actual data is over 70 fields and with two FK joins the initial 40000 rows is well in excess of 1.8 million once selected as a normal dataset.

EDIT: Just in case someone stumbles on this and are in the same situation I was in.

1. When preparing a sample record for the Past XML to class make sure you have more than one record if you are expecting something similar to my example above. (The class changes to support more than one record.)
2. You get very different results when searching for deserialize when doing your research. This small change resulted in me figuring out the issue.

Comment: Are you using Entity?  Entity create an EDMX mapping between the database and the c# classes.  The POCO is getting a response from Server which is a Controller and the processing of the controller response uses XML Serialization (deserialize) which puts results into classes.  The Entity classes and the XML Serialize classes may not be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am not using EF, I will do some Googling to see if it does what I need.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this, my solutions was found by a sutble change to the way I was searching. I needed the info from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27235951/deserialize-xml-string-to-object-vb-net), This pointed me in the direction of the attributes I needed to change in my class.

Comment: You could of used the attribute XmlArray set to Addresses and XmlArrayItem set to Address instead of creating another class : XmlArray("Addresses"),XmlArrayItem("Address")